# extract header if pattern in a column matches

Tags: linux, date, awk, sed, cut

I am trying to extract and print header of a file if the pattern in that particular column matches.

Here is a example :

```
[user ~]$ cal |sed 's/July 2014//'  
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31
```

Expected output :

if input date =31 then print the day on 31st.

Just to be clear, I cannot use date -d flag as its not supported by my OS.Probably would need awk here to crack the question.

```
[user ~]$ date -d 20140731 +%A  
Thursday
```

I hope I am able to convey my question and concern clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `gnu awk` solution:

```
cal | awk -v date=31 -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3" 'NR==2 {split($0,a)} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==date) print a[i]}'
Th
```

You set the `date` that you like to be displayed as a variable, so it can be change to what you like.

Or it could be written like this:

```
cal | awk 'NR==2 {split($0,a)} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==date) print a[i]}' FIELDWIDTHS="3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3" date=31
```

PS `FIELDWIDTH` was introduced in `gnu awk 2.31`

Comment: You beat me by 1 minute! You can just do `if($1==date)print a[i]`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, I do see that there should be only one hit, so no end section needed.  Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
cal | awk -v date=31 'NR == 2 { split($0, header) } NR > 2 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == date) { print header[NR == 3 ? i + 7 - NF : i]; exit } }'
```

Output:

```
Th
```

Comment: How do I set another date like `4` with this and get `Fr`?

Comment: Still not work. Date 4 gives `We`, correct is `Fr`and you miss a single quote at the end.

Comment: @Jotne Copy-paste mistake. Now fixed including the date problem.

Comment: +1 from me, for finding a way of not needing GNU awk's FIELDWIDTHS, which may be a blessing on the OP's box that can't even do `date` properly!

Comment: @konsolebox Now it does not work correctly more. I get `Sa` for `31`

Comment: In my `cal` implementation the current day get highlighted, s from 23 July this solution fails for me.

Comment: Solution found.  Using  `cal -h` does not highlight the current day.

Comment: @Jotne I fixed the problem for 31.

Comment: You do not need the `exit` and test for `NR>2` so it could be written some like this: `cal | awk 'NR==2 {split($0,h)} {for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i==date) print h[NR==3?i+7-NF:i]}' date=25` to shorten it some. And its nearly same as mine, except you do not use `filewidths` :)

Comment: @Jotne Yes but I'd choose having the exit command this time. Not having it may be shorter but it makes you calculate other lines unnecessarily. Still for such a short data some may think that it's not too necessary. Anyway, either way has its own advantage so it's just a preference in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the output of `cal` isn't really that advisable...

Can your OS's `date` handle `-j`?

```
date -j 073100002014 "+%a"
Thu
```

How is your OS at `perl`?

```
perl -MDateTime -E '$dt=DateTime->new(year=>2014,month=>7,day=>31);say $dt->day_name'
Thursday
```

Or, if it doesn't do `perl -E`, you could do

```
perl -MDateTime -e '$dt=DateTime->new(year=>2014,month=>7,day=>31);print $dt->day_name'
Thursday
```

How is your OS at `php`?

```
php -r '$jd=cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,7,31,2014);echo(jdk($jd,2));'
Thu
```

Comment: For perl, I'd suggest the core module [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) instead: `perl -mTime::Piece -E 'say Time::Piece->strptime("20140731","%Y%m%d")->fullday'`