# Need to minus one day from a date given

Tags: shell, date, unix, scripting

I have a variable output holding date as below:

output = "20141220"

I need to extract a day out of it and store it in another variable, i.e., something similar to below:

output1=20141219"

and if the month is changing, i.e., date in on 31st or 1st, it should be taken care of.

`date -d` is not supported in the version I am using, any leads will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Does your system have Perl or PHP? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919566/2836621

Comment: If you don't have a modern `date` binary I would avoid using Bash/shell scripts for this task - date-time handling is tricky and error prone. As Mark suggests identify a tool you *do* have on your system that can do date arithmetic for you and call into that, rather than trying to do the math yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You could check if it is the first day of the month, and if so, you can set the date one month back. You also have to check if its the first month of the year and set the year back if true.

```
if (dayofdate == 1) {
   //set one month back
   //set day of the month accordingly
} else if (monthofdate == 1){
   //set one year back
}
```

Comment: but how do I set it :D :D

Comment: Please [don't do manual date arithmetic](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).